# Proving the Wronskain of a second order ODE by the method of contradiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Theorem

Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable functions on an open interval $I$ and suppose
that there is $t_{0} ∈ I$ such that $W (f , g)(t_{0}) \neq  0$. Then $f$ and $g$ are linearly
independent.

Proof
:
Suppose, on the contrary, that $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent.
Let’s say $g = cf$ , where $c$ is a constant.
The Wronskian is then
$$w(t)=det
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
f & g \\
f' & g' \
  \
\end{array}
\right]
=det
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
f & cf \\
f' &cf' \
  \
\end{array}
\right]=0$$

This contradiction concludes the proof

What i did not understand about the proof is that, how does showing that the wronkskain of $f$ and $g$ being equals to $0$ is a contradiction  and hence able to prove the above theorem. COuld anyone please explain. Thanks

Comment: It contradicted the assumption that the wronskian was not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is simply the contraposition of what you want to show. It shows $$f,g \; \text{linearly dependent} \Rightarrow W(f,g)(t) = 0 \quad\forall t \in I$$

The contraposition of this statement is just

$$ \exists t_0 \in I: W(f,g)(t_0) \neq 0 \Rightarrow f,g \; \text{linearly independent}$$